# IOS:Retina Image comes out of the ImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, retina-display

I have one tableview in my View controller. 
i have one image named chkin.png (258x258) [image]
and another image for retina named chkin@2x.png(516x516) [image]

And in the storyboard i have defined the cell like 
[image]
And in cellForRowAtIndex method

```
[cell.imageView  setClipsToBounds:YES];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[cell.imageView setImage:image];
```

In normal iPhone there is no issues but in the retina display the image is slight out side the image view 
[image]

Please provide me the best way to do this

Comment: try commenting `contentMode `

Comment: You should try to set ContentMode (setContentMode:).
there are many option out there for content Mode, you can try those. I think 'UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit' will work for you.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I tried [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                        [cell.imageView setImage:image]; Still it not working

Comment: I am also dealing with the same problem that he faced .... Please anyone provide one immediately.....